# pagination fails when including custom variable in permalinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination, permalinks

I'm a wordpress newbie here so please go easy on me.

I am working on a wordpress site and I've run into two problems I just can't seem to find the answer to anywhere. I have permalinks set up on my wordpress site, along with paging, so for example, www.mysite.com/links/page/2 sends you to the second page of links.

I just created a custom template that pulls in two different taxonomies with the same tag name. To do that I created a page called tags that uses my custom template and I have a custom link that goes to it with a structure of: www.mysite.com/tags/?tag=mytag This is ugly but it works for testing purposes.

The problem happens when I go to page two and the link is: www.mysite.com/tags/?tag=mytag/page/2 which doesn't work.

I don't want to mess up my current permalinks, but I want to add a new rule that a) stops the page from breaking, and b) actually looks good. I would like to have the link just be  www.mysite.com/tags/mytag/page/2

After a ton of digging I was able to get what I thought was the right code. This is what I've added to my functions.php in my theme directory:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_tag_rewrite_rules' );
//add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_tag_query_vars' );

function my_tag_query_vars( $vars )
{
    // $vars[] = 'tag'; // might not need this because 'tag' should already be         registered
}
function my_tag_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'tags/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . 'tags/?tag=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
        'tags/([^/]+)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . 'tags/?tag=' .     $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 )

    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

(I commented out the add_filter part because 'tag' was already a query variable wordpress recognized). From what I read it looked like all I needed to do was go into the wordpress dashboard and go to settings->permalinks and supposedly it would change the .htaccess. It didn't.

My first question, is: is my rewrite rule correct? and secondly, what else do I need to do to get wordpress to update the .htaccess file?

Thanks a ton for any help!